# How do I commit / update svn in phpstorm 8.0.3?

Tags: svn, phpstorm

How can I commit and update on a certain files or folder in phpstorm 8.0.3? I don't see any commit button on it.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/subversion-reference.html) at all? It's all pretty much in there. Ctrl-K is the default hotkey for committing changes, given that you have any versioning system configured.